PNP SPFx dynamic form customizer set value of a field
I'm using PNP SPFx react controls to create a customized form for a SharePoint online list. This is all set up and working.
One of the fields in the form needs to be set automatically and I can't find any tutorials on how to set the value of a field. Is there a way to do this or do I need to write a custom field override? I was following this tutorial for the basic set up.
I would like the field to remain visible to the user while they fill out the rest of the form, but this specific automatic field would be disabled.
